# Django unique field ignored in interactive shell

Tags: django, django-shell

I've defined a class called Country that has a unique name field.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

On the admin page, this behaves as I'd expect it to. Creating a country that is already in the database fails with the error "Country with this Name already exists.". Perfect.

When I try to test the same thing in the interactive prompt (`manage.py shell`), no such error is given. Instead the duplicate object is just added to the database.

```
>>> from rack.models import Country
>>> usa = Country(name="United States of America")
>>> usa.save()
>>> canada = Country(name="United States of America")
>>> canada.save()
>>> canada.name
'United States of America'
>>> Country.objects.all()
[<Country: United States of America>, <Country: United States of America>]
```

I'm quite new to Django, can anyone enlighten me as to why the shell ignores the unique field?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about the enforcement of 'unique', but you might find this useful: http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/. I'm not the author but I've used it in a project or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you reset your DB table? My guess is that you defined the model previously without unique=True.

The docs say that unique is enforced at the admin level and the database level, which matches your symptoms! That is.. it works in admin, not in shell.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique

Comment: I dropped the table (it was an early work in progress anyway) and did another syncdb. Now the shell gives me `IntegrityError: duplicate key violates unique constraint "rack_country_name_key"` Thanks for solving this mystery!

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? If you are using sqlite and South, there is [a bug](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/144) which doesn't allow adding unique constraints so sqlite tables.

If that's the case, it may be that the admin form enforces the uniqueness, so the check never even gets to the database, but when you do it from the command line, it's relying on the database to enforce uniqueness (which sqlite doesn't do in this case).

Comment: I'm running a PostgreSQL 8.1.22 database.

Comment: +1 since technically it could have been the right answer to my question. It might help someone else experiencing the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `Country` you're loading from `rack.models` is using the version you think it is?  I'd check the `__file__` on it and make sure it's not using some cached version of it.  Or if you modify the model after it's imported it wouldn't necessarily trip that.

`unique` **should** enforce uniqueness at both the model *and* the database layer